# Object-oriented text-based RPG with randomized enemies and loot in Java

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented, role-playing-game

I'm currently in the process of creating a RPG in Java in order to practice and learn the ins and outs of the language. I have been learning to code for around 1 month through Code HS, and coding within their Sandbox tool. Any general help would be greatly appreciated.

Specifically, I am not satisfied with the `Inventory` system, and how it deals with items of different sub-classes such as `Weapon`s or `Consumable`s. I am not sure if a HashMap is the best collection to go about achieving this, as I need to store and retrieve the objects themselves and the quantity of them.

This is the main class that handles inputs and outputs as well as the various events a user can choose to do:

```
//Fishing/hunting for consumables

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyProgram extends ConsoleProgram{
    public String ind = "-----";
    public String header = "+++++++++++++++++";
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void run(){
        String userName = prompt("What is your name: ");
        Player user = new Player(userName);
        Weapon starter1 = new Weapon(2);
        Weapon starter2 = new Weapon(3);

        Consumable chicken = new Consumable("Chicken Breast", 20, 1);
        user.addToInventory(starter1, 1);
        user.addToInventory(starter2, 1);
        user.addToInventory(chicken, 3);

        String userInput = prompt("\nWhat would you like to do (Type Commands to see a list): ");
        while(!userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("DONE")){

            switch(userInput.toUpperCase()){
                case "COMMANDS" :
                    System.out.println(header);
                    System.out.println("Commands: Battle, Attributes, Check Inventory, Stats"); 
                    break;
                case "BATTLE": 
                    System.out.println(header);
                    battle(user); 
                    break;
                case "ATTRIBUTES":
                    System.out.println(header);
                    attribute(user);
                    break;
                case "CHECK INVENTORY":
                    System.out.println(header);
                    inventory(user);
                    break;
                case "STATS":
                    System.out.println(header);
                    stats(user);
                    break;

                default: 
                    System.out.println("Choose a correct command (Type Commands to see a list)");
                    break;
            }
            if(user.isDead()){
                user.deathPenalty();
                System.out.println("\nYou are revived, at the cost of half your gold and your current weapon" );
                user.incrementCurHp(user.getMaxHp());
            }
            if(user.isDead()){
                break;
            }else{
                userInput = prompt("\nWhat would you like to do: ");
            }
        }
    }
    public String equip(Player player, Weapon item){
        if(player.equipWeapon(item)){
            return ind + player.getName() + " successfully equipped " + item.getName(); 
        }else{
            return ind + player.getName() + " failed to equip " + item.getName(); 
        }
    }
    public String consume(Player player, Consumable item){
        if(player.useConsumable(item)){
            return ind + player.getName() + " consumed a " + item.getName() + " and gained " + item.getHeal() + " Hp";
        }else{
            return ind + player.getName() + " failed to consume a " + item.getName();
        }
    }
    public String prompt(String question){
        System.out.print(question);
        String input = s.nextLine();
        return input;
    }

    public int promptInt(String question){
        while(true){
            String input = prompt(question);
            try{
                int n = Integer.parseInt(input);
                return n;
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){

            }
        }
    }

    public boolean rollAgility(Creature attacker, int high){
        int roll = GameRandom.range(1, high);
        if(roll <= attacker.agilityBonus()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String attack(Creature one, Creature two){
        boolean crit = rollAgility(one, 100);
        int a = one.attack(two, crit);
        if(crit){
            return one.getName() + " CRITICAL hit " + two.getName() + " for " + a + " damage.";
        }else{
            return one.getName() + " hit " + two.getName() + " for " + a + " damage.";
        }
    }

    public void battle(Player player){

        //Generation of a random Monster with a random Weapon of the monster's level
        Monster encounter = new Monster(player.getLevel() + 1);
        Weapon randomWeapon = new Weapon(encounter.getLevel());
        encounter.equipWeapon(randomWeapon);
        encounter.incrementCurHp(encounter.getMaxHp());

        System.out.println(ind + "You encounter " + encounter.getName());
        System.out.println(ind + encounter.getWeapon());
        String input = prompt("\n" + ind + "What do you do (Type Choices to see a list): ");

        while(!player.isDead() && !encounter.isDead()){
            boolean run = false;
            switch(input.toUpperCase()){
                case "CHOICES": 
                    System.out.println(ind + "Attack, Run, Inventory(code this)");
                    input = prompt(ind + "What do you do: ");
                    continue; 
                case "ATTACK":
                    System.out.println(ind + attack(player, encounter));
                    System.out.println(ind + encounter.status());
                    break;
                case "RUN":
                    run = rollAgility(player, 25);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println(ind + "Choose a correct choice (Type Choices to see a list)");
                    input = prompt(ind + "What do you do: ");
                    continue; 
            }

            if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("run")){
                if(run){
                    System.out.println(ind + "You succeed at running");
                    break;
                }else{
                System.out.println(ind + "You fail at running");
                }
            }

            if(encounter.isDead()){
                System.out.println("\n" + ind + "You killed " + encounter.getName());
                System.out.println(ind + "You gain " + player.gainBattleXp(encounter) + " exp");
                if(player.checkXp()){
                    System.out.println(ind + "You leveled up, your health is restored and you gain 1 attribute point!");
                }
                System.out.println(ind + "You gained "  + player.gainBattleGold(encounter) + " gold");
                System.out.println(ind + "You have " + player.getXp() + " exp");

                int roll = GameRandom.range(1, 20);
                if(roll <= 5){
                    System.out.println(ind + "You find a " + randomWeapon.getName() + "!");
                    player.addToInventory(randomWeapon, 1);
                }

                break;
            }
            System.out.println(ind + attack(encounter, player));
            System.out.println(ind + player.status());

            if(player.isDead()){
                System.out.println("\n" + ind + "You fainted!");
                break;
            }
            input = prompt("\n" + ind + "What do you do: ");
        }
    }

    public void attribute(Player player){
        System.out.println(ind + "Your attribute points: " + player.getAtPoints() + "\n" +
                           ind + "Strength: " + player.getStrength() + "\n" +
                           ind + "Intellect: " + player.getIntellect() + "\n" +
                           ind + "Agility: " + player.getAgility() + "\n" +
                           ind + "Vitality: " + player.getVitality() + "\n");

        if(player.getAtPoints() > 0){
            String use = prompt(ind + "Do you want to use your " + player.getAtPoints() + " attribute points (Yes or No): ");
            if(use.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
                String choice = prompt(ind + "What attribute do you want to be increased: ");
                int amount = promptInt(ind + "How many attribute points do you want to spend on it: ");

                while(player.getAtPoints() > 0){
                        if(amount <= player.getAtPoints()){
                            switch(choice.toUpperCase()){
                                case "STRENGTH": 
                                    player.getAt().increaseStrength(amount);
                                    player.incrementAtPoints(-amount);
                                    System.out.println(ind + "Your base Strength is now: " + player.getAt().getStrength());
                                    break;
                                case "INTELLECT":
                                    player.getAt().increaseIntellect(amount);
                                    player.incrementAtPoints(-amount);
                                    System.out.println(ind + "Your base Intellect is now: " + player.getAt().getIntellect());
                                    break;
                                case "AGILITY":
                                    player.getAt().increaseAgility(amount);
                                    player.incrementAtPoints(-amount);
                                    System.out.println(ind + "Your base Agility is now: " + player.getAt().getAgility());
                                    break;
                                case "VITALITY":
                                    player.getAt().increaseVitality(amount);
                                    player.incrementAtPoints(-amount);
                                    System.out.println(ind + "Your base Vitality is now: " + player.getAt().getVitality());
                                    player.applyVitality();
                                    break;
                                case "DONE":
                                    amount = -1;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    System.out.println(ind + "Choose a correct attribute.");
                                    break;
                            }
                            if(amount == -1){
                                break;
                            }
                            System.out.println(ind + "You have " + player.getAtPoints() + " attribute points left");
                            if(player.getAtPoints() == 0){
                                break;
                            }
                            choice = prompt(ind + "What attribute do you want to be increased: ");
                            amount = promptInt(ind + "How many attribute points do you want to spend on it: ");

                        }else{ 
                            System.out.println(ind + "You do not have that many attribute points");
                            choice = prompt(ind + "What attribute do you want to be increased: ");
                            amount = promptInt(ind + "How many attribute points do you want to spend on it: "); 
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void inventory(Player player){
        System.out.println(player.checkInventory(player));
        String ask = prompt(ind + "Do you want to equip a weapon or use a consumable: ");
        if(ask.equalsIgnoreCase("Equip a Weapon")){
            String equip = prompt(ind + "What do you want to equip: ");
            try{
                Item test = player.stringToItem(equip);
                if(player.stringToItem(equip).getType().equalsIgnoreCase("Weapon")){
                    test = (Weapon)test;
                    System.out.println(equip(player, (Weapon)player.stringToItem(equip)));
                }else{
                    System.out.println(ind + "You cannot equip that");
                }
            }catch(NullPointerException e){
                System.out.println(ind + "Invalid weapon");
            }
        }else if(ask.equalsIgnoreCase("Use a Consumable")){
            String consumable = prompt(ind + "What do you want to use: ");
            try{
                Item test = player.stringToItem(consumable);
                if(test.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("Consumable")){
                    test = (Consumable)test;
                    System.out.println(consume(player, (Consumable)player.stringToItem(consumable)));    
                }else{
                    System.out.println(ind + "You cannot consume that");
                }
            }catch(NullPointerException e){
                System.out.println(ind + "Invalid consumable");
            }
        }
    }

    public void stats(Player player){
        System.out.println(ind + player.getWeapon() + ind);
        System.out.println(ind + player.status());
        System.out.println(ind +  "Level: " + player.getLevel());
        System.out.println(ind + "Exp: " + player.getXp());
    }
}
```

The `GameRandom` class handles generation of random numbers and random names/stats for `Monster`s and `Weapon`s:

```
public class GameRandom{

    //Handles all random events such as pulling a number from a range or generating a name/stats
    public static int roll(int sides){
        int aRoll = (int)(Math.random() * sides + 1);
        return aRoll;
    }
    public static int range(double min, double max){
        return (int)(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }


    public static String monsterName(){
        String[] names = {"Spooky", "Scary", "Yup", "Yessir", "Grumblegore", "Minotaur"};
        int index = (int)(Math.random() * names.length);

        return names[index];
    }
    public static Attributes monsterAttributes(int level){
        int str = (int)(level * Math.random() + 2);
        int intel = (int)(level * Math.random() + 2);
        int agil = (int)(level * Math.random() + 2);
        int vit = (int)(level * Math.random() + 2.5);

        Attributes x = new Attributes(str, intel, agil, vit);
        return x;
    }

    public static String weaponName(int level){
        String output = "";
        output += "Lv" + level + " ";
        String[] prefix;
        String[] base;
        String[] suffix;
        String suf = "";
        if(level <= 5){
            prefix = new String[]{"Broken" , "Bronze", "Copper", "Weak", "Training", "Fragile"};
        }else if(level <= 10){
            prefix = new String[]{"Iron", "Silver", "Cold Iron", "Darkwood", "Bone", "Reinforced"};
        }else{
            prefix = new String[]{"Gilded", "Warrior's", "Absolute", "Golden", "Mithril", "Holy", "Demonic"};
            suffix = new String[]{"Of Destruction", "Of Fear", "Of Spooks", "Of Serenity", "Of Hope", "Of Despair", "Of Depression"};

            int sIndex = (int)(Math.random() * suffix.length);
            suf += " " + suffix[sIndex];
        }
        base = new String[]{"Lance", "Sword", "Dagger", "Staff", "Mace", "Pole", "Spear", "Halberd", "Scythe", "Knife", "Shiv", "Nunchucks", "Gauntlets", "Flail", "Morning Star" };
        int bIndex = (int)(Math.random() * base.length);
        int pIndex = (int)(Math.random() * prefix.length);

        output += prefix[pIndex] + " ";
        output += base[bIndex];
        if(level > 10){
            output += suf;
        }

        return output;

    }

    public static Attributes weaponAttributes(int level){
        int str = (int)(level * Math.random());
        int intel = (int)(level * Math.random());
        int agil = (int)(level * Math.random());
        int vit = (int)(level * Math.random());

        Attributes x = new Attributes(str, intel, agil, vit);
        return x;
    }


}
```

This is the `Creature` class, from which the `Player` and `Monster` classes extend:

```
public abstract class Creature{

    public String name;
    public int baseHp;
    public int maxHp;
    public int curHp;
    public int maxAtt;
    public int level;
    public Attributes attr;
    public Weapon equippedWeapon;
    public Weapon fists = new Weapon("Fists" , 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0);

    public Creature(String name, int baseHp, int maxAtt, int level){
        this.name = name;
        this.level = level;
        this.maxAtt = maxAtt;
        this.attr = new Attributes(0, 0, 0 ,0);
        this.equippedWeapon = fists;
        this.baseHp = baseHp;
        this.applyVitality();
        this.curHp = maxHp;
    }
    //Names and Statuses
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getWeapon(){
        return name + " is wielding " + equippedWeapon.getName();
    }

    public String status(){
        this.applyVitality();
        return name + " has " + curHp + "/" + maxHp + " Hp.";
    }
    public int getLevel(){
        return level;
    }
    public int getMaxHp(){
        return maxHp;
    }
    //Weapons


    //Battle Methods
    public int attack(Creature other, boolean crit){
        int att = maxAtt + (int)(this.strengthBonus() * level)/3;
        int roll = GameRandom.range(1, 100);
        //Pulls a boolean from the input that way crits can be announced in MyProgram
        if(crit){
            att *= 1.75;
        }
        int minAtt = (int)(att * .7);
        att = GameRandom.range(minAtt, att);
        other.incrementCurHp(-att);

        return att;
    }
     public void incrementCurHp(int amount){
        applyVitality();
        curHp += amount;
        if(curHp >= maxHp){
            curHp = maxHp;
        }else if(curHp <= 0){
            curHp = 0;
        } 
    }
    public int getCurHp(){
        return curHp;
    }

    public int getMaxAtt(){
        return maxAtt;
    }

    public boolean isDead(){
        return curHp <= 0;
    }

    //Attributes
    public Attributes getAt(){
        return attr;
    }

    public String getStrength(){
        return this.getAt().getStrength() + " + " + this.equippedWeapon.getAt().getStrength();
    }

    public int strengthBonus(){
        return this.getAt().getStrength() + this.equippedWeapon.getAt().getStrength();
    }

    public String getIntellect(){
        return this.getAt().getIntellect() +" + " + this.equippedWeapon.getAt().getIntellect();
    }
    public int intellectBonus(){
        return this.getAt().getIntellect() + this.equippedWeapon.getAt().getIntellect();
    }

    public String getAgility(){
        return this.getAt().getAgility() + " + " + this.equippedWeapon.getAt().getAgility();
    }

    public int agilityBonus(){
        return this.getAt().getAgility() + this.equippedWeapon.getAt().getAgility();
    }

    public String getVitality(){
        return this.getAt().getVitality() +  " + " +this.equippedWeapon.getAt().getVitality();
    }

    public int vitalityBonus(){
        return this.getAt().getVitality() + this.equippedWeapon.getAt().getVitality();
    }
    public void applyVitality(){
        this.maxHp = (this.vitalityBonus() * level) + baseHp;
    }
}
```

`Attribute` class, the stats bonuses for `Creatures` and `Weapons`

```
 public class Attributes{
    public int strength;
    public int intellect;
    public int agility;
    public int vitality;

    public Attributes(int strength, int intellect, int agility, int vitality){
        this.strength = strength;
        this.intellect = intellect;
        this.agility = agility;
        this.vitality = vitality;
    }
    public int getStrength(){
        return strength;
    }
    public int getIntellect(){
        return intellect;
    }
    public int getAgility(){
        return agility;
    }
    public int getVitality(){
        return vitality;
    }
    public void increaseStrength(int amount){
        strength += amount;
    }
    public void increaseIntellect(int amount){
        intellect += amount;
    }
    public void increaseAgility(int amount){
        agility += amount;
    }
    public void increaseVitality(int amount){
        vitality += amount;
    }
}
```

`Player` class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Player extends Creature{

    public int gold;
    Attributes playerAttr;
    public int xp = 0;
    public int xpThreshold = 80;
    public int attributePoints;
    Inventory playerInv;

    public Player(String name){
        super(name, 25, 15, 1);
        this.maxHp = baseHp;
        this.attr = new Attributes(0, 0 , 1, 0);
        this.playerInv = new Inventory(this);
        this.attributePoints = 5;
        this.gold = 0;
    }  
    //equipping/unequipping weapons as it pertains to the player's inventory
    public boolean equipWeapon(Weapon weapon){
        if(weapon.getLevel() <= this.level){
            if(this.getHashMap().containsKey(weapon)){
                if(playerInv.incrementAmount(weapon, -1)){
                    this.unequipWeapon();
                    this.equippedWeapon = weapon;
                    this.applyVitality();
                    this.incrementCurHp(0);
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }else{
            this.incrementCurHp(0);
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void unequipWeapon(){
        this.addToInventory(this.equippedWeapon, 1);
        this.equippedWeapon = fists;
        this.incrementCurHp(0);
    }
    //XP and Level ups
    public void levelUp(){
        level++;
        this.baseHp += level * 3;
        this.maxAtt += (int)(level * 1.5);
        this.applyVitality();
        this.curHp = this.maxHp;

        attributePoints++;
    }
    public void setXpThreshold(){
        if(this.level <=2){
            xpThreshold = this.level * 80; 
        }else{
            xpThreshold = this.level * (this.level - 2) * 120;
        }    
    }

    public int gainBattleXp(Creature other){
        int base = other.level * 40;
        int gain = GameRandom.range(base * 1.3, (base * .7));

        xp += gain;
        return gain;
    }
    public boolean checkXp(){
        this.setXpThreshold();

        if(xp >= xpThreshold){
            xp -= xpThreshold;
            this.levelUp();
            this.setXpThreshold();

            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public int gainBattleGold(Creature other){
        int money = other.level * 40;
        int gain = GameRandom.range(money * 1.3, money * .7);

        this.gold += gain;
        return gain;
    }
    public String getXp(){
        this.setXpThreshold();
        return xp + "/" + xpThreshold;
    }

    //Attribute Points
    public int getAtPoints(){
        return attributePoints;
    }
    public void incrementAtPoints(int amount){
        attributePoints += amount;
    }
    //Inventory, HashMap with item keys and amount values
    public String checkInventory(Player player){
        return "-----Your Gold: " + this.gold + "\n" + playerInv.checkInventory(player);
    }
    public void addToInventory(Item item, int amount){
        if(this.getHashMap().containsKey(item)){
            playerInv.incrementAmount(item, amount);
        }else{
            this.getHashMap().put(item, amount);
        }
    }
    public boolean removeFromInventory(Item item, int amount){
        if(this.getHashMap().containsKey(item)){
            if(playerInv.incrementAmount(item, amount)){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public Inventory getInventory(){
        return playerInv;
    }
    public HashMap<Item, Integer> getHashMap(){
        return playerInv.inventory;
    }
    public boolean checkInventoryFor(String input){
        for(Item key: getHashMap().keySet()){
            if(input.equalsIgnoreCase(key.getName())){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }    

        }
        return true;
    }
    public Item stringToItem(String input){
        for(Item key: this.getHashMap().keySet()){
            if(key.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(input)){
                return key;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public boolean useConsumable(Consumable item){
        if(this.getHashMap().containsKey(item)){
            if(playerInv.incrementAmount(item, -1)){
                this.applyVitality();
                this.incrementCurHp(item.getHeal());
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void deathPenalty(){
        this.gold = (int)(this.gold * .5);
        this.equippedWeapon = fists;
    }
}
```

`Monster` class:

```
public class Monster extends Creature{


    //Hand created Monster
    public Monster(String name, int maxHp, int maxAtt, int level){
        super(name, maxHp, maxAtt, level);
        this.attr = GameRandom.monsterAttributes(level);
        this.applyVitality();
        this.curHp = this.maxHp;
    }  
    //Randomly genereated Monster of a certain level
    public Monster(int level){
        super(GameRandom.monsterName(), 20, 10, level);
        this.attr = GameRandom.monsterAttributes(level);
        this.applyVitality();
        this.curHp = this.maxHp;
    }

    public void equipWeapon(Weapon weapon){
        this.equippedWeapon = weapon;
        this.applyVitality();
    }


}
```

`Item` class, from which `Weapon` and `Consumable` extend:

```
public class Item{

    public String name;
    public Attributes attr;

    public String type;

    public Item(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.attr = new Attributes(0, 0 ,0 ,0);
        this.type = "item";
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }
    public Attributes getAt(){
        return attr;
    }

    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }
}
```

`Weapon` class:

```
public class Weapon extends Item{

    Attributes weaponAttr;
    public int level;

    public Weapon(String name, int strength, int magic, int agility, int vitality, int level){
        super(name);
        this.weaponAttr = new Attributes(strength, magic, agility, vitality);
        this.level = level;
        this.type = "Weapon";
    }
    public Weapon(int level){
        super(GameRandom.weaponName(level));
        this.weaponAttr = GameRandom.weaponAttributes(level);
        this.level = level;
        this.type = "Weapon";
    }
    public Attributes getAt(){
        return weaponAttr;
    }
    public int getLevel(){
        return level;
    }
}
```

`Consumable` class:

```
public class Consumable extends Item{

    public int heal;
    public int level;

    public Consumable(String name, int heal, int level){
        super(name);
        this.heal = heal;
        this.level = level;
        this.type = "Consumable";
    } 
    //Create a second constructor to generate a random consumable from a level
    //Create name databases within GameRandom for fishing/hunting
    public int getHeal(){
        return heal;
    }
}
```

And finally the `Inventory` class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Inventory{
    public Creature owner;
    public HashMap<Item , Integer> inventory = new HashMap<Item , Integer>();

    public Inventory(Creature owner){
        this.owner = owner;
    }
    public boolean incrementAmount(Item item, int change){
        if(change > 0){
            int oldValue = inventory.get(item);
            int newValue = oldValue + change;
            inventory.put(item, newValue);
            return true;
        }else{
            if(inventory.get(item) >= change){
                int oldValue  = inventory.get(item);
                int newValue = oldValue + change;
                inventory.put(item, newValue);
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }  
    }


    }
    public HashMap<Item, Integer> inventory(){
        return inventory;
    }
    //Consider splitting inventory into two/three hashmaps (Weapon, Consumable, collectible etc)
    public String checkInventory(Player player){
        String output = "";
        for(Item key: inventory.keySet()){
            if(!(key.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Fists"))){
                Integer amount = inventory.get(key);
                if(amount > 0){
                    String name = key.getName();
                    output += "-----" + name; 
                    if(key.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("Weapon")){
                        key = (Weapon)key;
                        int str = key.getAt().getStrength();
                        int inte = key.getAt().getIntellect();
                        int agi = key.getAt().getAgility();
                        int vit = key.getAt().getVitality();
                        output += "(" + str  + ", " + inte + ", " + agi + ", " + vit + ")";
                    }
                    output += ": " + amount + "\n";
                }
            }

        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Consumable` is extending `Item`, but is not using `attribute`, so i would get rid of attribute in `item`.

You could extend `Item` with the fields `amount` and `stackable` and remove `attr`

Then extend `Item` with the following methods (Also add removeItem)

```
public int getAmount(){
  return amount;
}

public boolean addToStack(){
  if(stackable){
    amount++;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Now i would instead use a `HashMap<String, Item>` because it would be easier to add and remove stuff from your inventory.

```
public class Inventory{
  private Map<String, Item> inventory;

  public Inventory(Create owner){
    this.inventory = new HashMap<String, Item>();
  }

  public boolean addItem(Item item){
    if(!inventory.containsKey(item.getName()){
      inventory.put(item.getName(), item);
      return true;
    }
    else if(inventory.containsKey(item.getName()) && item.isStackable()){
      inventory.get(item.getName()).addToStack();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public String checkInventory(){
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     List<Item> items = inventory.values();
     for(Item item : items){
        builder.append(item.getName());
        if(item instanceof Weapon){
           Weapon weapon = (Weapon)item;
           Attribute attribute = weapon.getAttribute();
           builder.append(atrribute.getStrength());
           //etc. 
        }
        builder.append(item.getAmount());
     }
     return builder.toString();
  }
}
```

Considering that you usually can have many different items in your inventory, it wouldn't make sense to separate them into different HashMaps, but instead make `Item` smaller, then use instanceof to figure out what class it is.